# Can anyone tell me SOA TTL versus RR TTL

Tags: windows-server-2008

From what i have searched SOA TTL has the default value & for RR TTL are option.Can some one please clear me what is the actual difference between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTL in a resource record is fairly obvious - it's the cache time for that particular record. In a BIND zone file the RR TTL can be set globally or overridden on a single record:

```
$TTL 86400
mydynamicrecord.mydomain.com   300   IN   A   1.2.3.4
```

The MINIMUM TTL field in the SOA has two uses.

1. A global minimum for all the records. If you specify a smaller TTL on any record, the SOA minimum will be used instead. From the RFC:

   > Whenever a RR is sent in a response to a
   >   query, the TTL field is set to the maximum of the TTL field from the RR
   >   and the MINIMUM field in the appropriate SOA.  Thus MINIMUM is a lower
   >   bound on the TTL field for all RRs in a zone.
2. As the TTL for 'negative' responses - i.e. how long resolvers can cache a response for records in this zone that don't exist. If a resolver attempts to lookup `invalidhost.mydomain.com`, the resolver can cache the 'doesn't exist' response for the time specified in the MINIMUM field which helps keep DNS traffic down.